# An expression to describe a place that is very accessible and convenient

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, idiom-request

is there a phrase/expressions/idiom that is related to nearby distances and/or easy accessibility? For example,

1. Within reach
2. A stone's throw away
3. At your service

I'm creating a title for a property that has an excellent location - it's right smacked in the middle of everywhere, near to public transportation, other shopping malls, offices etc.

Comment: You're halfway there..."conveniently located"

Comment: A property that is near to many things is often described as "in the middle of everything".  For example, here's someone giving that title to an AirBNB property: https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/5650539

Comment: The idiom is not _Smack**ed** in the middle._ Use just _smack_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options...

> Located *in the heart of the city*

may work.

These days, 'heart' does not mean the exact center of the city. The term is also used for the site located in the area whence malls, transporting stations, etc. are nearby.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

> In the Middle of it All

as in

> Great location, in the middle of it all.  Stores, museums, restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice to use the term *"within walking distance"* as a measure of convenience when describing property location in my home country. For example:

> Large, two bedroom apartment, in the city centre.
>
> Located **within walking distance** of downtown and XXX metro stop.

That's not to say that one *must* walk to these locations, but rather to highlight that they are close enough for walking to be convenient.

Comment: Comedian Steven Wright had a line that everything is within walking distance if you have enough time.  :-)